# IOS: go to link in ios5 crash app

Tags: ios5

In my app I use this instruction in an ibaction to open safari and go to the link:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];
```

but the problem is that in IOS 5 it don't work fine because it open safari and go to the link but when I return in the app I have only a black screen and the app don't run. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the problem is that that when I go to background I close a view with view.parentViewController dismissModalViewController ad in ios5 it don't work, now it work

Answer (score 0):

Where did you test your app? simulator or a real iPhone? The way you did is right. I have a similar app offer the browser open up thing, and it worked fine both on simulator 5.0 and iphone 4 running iOS 5.0